# 12.10 on Elitebook 8560w w/ WUBI

Tags: boot, 12.10, dual-boot, wubi, installation

I am trying dual boot Windows 7 and Ubuntu on my Elitebook 8560w via WUBI.  Between Microsoft and HP they used up all my primary partitions so I decided WUBI was the best way to go.  It all goes smoothly until I reboot to finish the installation, then it hangs at copying files.  It always freezes here:

```
debconf (filter): widget found for ubiquity/install/title
debconf (filter): --> 0 OK
```

It also says something about "so and so might freeze best to kill it" but I didn't get it written down.

Can anybody tell me what that means?

EDIT:
This is what it says (In Full):

```
ubuntu kernel: [365.130914] [<c1064d607>] ? kthread_freezable_should_stop+0x60/0x60  
ubuntu kernel: [365.130914] [<c15d04fe7>] kernel_thread_helper+0x6/0x10  
debconf (filter): <-- progress set 49  
debconf (filter): widget found for ubiquity/install/title   
debconf (filter): --> 0 OK  
debconf (filter): <-- progress set 50
```

EDIT:
I tried again and it got a little further.

```
ubuntu kernel: [365.130914] [&#60;c1064d607>] ? kthread_freezable_should_stop+0x60/0x60  
ubuntu kernel: [365.130914] [&#60;c15d04fe7>] kernel_thread_helper+0x6/0x10  
debconf (filter): <-- progress set 49  
debconf (filter): widget found for ubiquity/install/title    
debconf (filter): --> 0 OK  
debconf (filter): <-- progress set 50  
debconf (filter): widget found for ubiquity/install/title  
debconf (filter): --> 0 OK`  
debconf (filter): <-- progress set 51  
debconf (filter): widget found for ubiquity/install/title  
debconf (filter): --> 0 OK`  
debconf (filter): <-- progress set 52
```

It went on like that for a long time, always incrementing `progress set` by one.  Then I got:

```
ubuntu CRON[10439]:(root) CMD( cd/ && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
ubuntu kernel: [2385.874396] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: >irq 55 for MSI-x
```

It was like that all night.

EDIT:
I tried again, putting "nomodeset" after "quiet splash" in GRUB.  Its going on three hours now....

Comment: Perhaps you should try again and try to get some more details about the error message--or better yet, the exact message. As it stands now, without those details, it will be nearly impossible to find the solution.

Comment: Ok, I'll go get it.

Comment: what graphics card do you have. freezes like this are common with radeon/nvidia cards. Use `nomodeset` to boot. The text displayed on the screen is normal with wubi installs when run standalone (liveimage installs), and doesn't show the cause of the freeze (after which logging messages doesn't work).

Comment: Ok.  I have the NVIDIA Quadro 1000M.  Can you explain how to use nomodeset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I feel stupid.  The problem turned out to be the i386 version of 12.10 I was using.  Got the AMD64 version and its all working just fine now.